# Incorrect Syntax Near 'Student'

Tags: c#, mysql

I am attempting to create a function that will allow a variable assignment, but i keep getting an error:

```
private static void DatabaseSelect(string ToBeSelected, string WhichTable, string Equality1, string Equality12)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Connection");
    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Firstname FROM Student WHERE User_ID = '" + "001" + "'", con);
    //var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT '"+ToBeSelected+"' FROM '"+WhichTable+ "' WHERE '"+Equality1+"' = '"+Equality12+"'", con);
    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = cmd };
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    Console.WriteLine( dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][ToBeSelected].ToString());
}
```

When I use the line

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Firstname FROM Student WHERE User_ID = '" + "001" + "'", con);
```

It should theoretically, when the variables equal the same string as the line above, be the same as the line

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT '"+ToBeSelected+"' FROM '"+WhichTable+ "' WHERE '"+Equality1+"' = '"+Equality12+"'", con);
```

But when I try to run the lower line it gives the error message (At the line Filling dataAdapter):

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'Student'."

If I am unclear please say so.Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Wrong tag. This belongs to C++ tag.

Comment: @Nguaial I think you mean C#.

Comment: @George - I know this is not C.  That Console.writeln() statement doesn't look like C++.  It must be C#.  I am C# illiterate.  Sorry.  (OO)

Comment: @Nguaial `var` and `private static` give it away too, if it wasn't for `private static` we wouldn't really be sure it's not C++ because of the typedef madness people get up to :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see some issues with your MySQL syntax

```
SELECT '"+ToBeSelected+"' FROM '"+WhichTable+ "' WHERE '"+Equality1+"' = '"+Equality12+"'"
```

Should translate to a MySQL Statement of:

```
 SELECT 'ColumnName' FROM 'TableName' WHERE 'ColumnName2' = 'SomeValue'"
```

The first issue I'm seeing is all the single quotes..   Column names, tables names should be surrounded by "ticks" (the button to the left of the 1) not Single quotes.

I would start there, I'm reading further into you code now.

Comment: Strangely enough, removing the single quotes actually fixed this problem. I for some reason thought these single quotes had to be used, and I've used them in ever other statement I've made, but I guess that's not the case. Thank you.

Comment: 'SomeValue' is definitely a valid statement, Thats because you would be saying SomeValue is a string.   but as for column names and table names, it is often easy to confuse the "tick" for a single quote.  and in the case of column names and table names, MySQL does NOT let you do single quotes.. "Ticks" or Nothing are both allowed though.